# How to absolute number elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this kind of list:

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>Title 1
  <ul>
   <li>Content 1.1</li>
   <li>Content 1.2</li>
   <li>Content 1.3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Title 2
  <ul>
   <li>Content 2.1</li>
   <li>Content 2.2</li>
   <li>Content 2.3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add an attribute value with its index number in each of the last level of li element, like data-number='1' to data-number='6'.

The first level of li element, where are the titles, should be ignored.

I tryed lots of thing like this:

```
$('ul#list ul li').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-number',$(this).index() + 1);
});
```

But it returns:

- data-number='1'
- data-number='2'
- data-number='3'
- data-number='1'
- data-number='2'
- data-number='3'

I just matched and added the attribute, I'm not able to make it count 1 to 6.

I can't change the html tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul#list ul li').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('data-number',idx + 1);
});
```

Comment: And he can also use `.data('number')` instead of `.attr('data-number')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
I dont undertand how it works. What should I read to know more about it?

Comment: Great, feel free to mark this as the answer if it helped. You can always refer to the excellent jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Yes, their docs are great, I'm always checking it, but as an autodidact I've never thought about use that argument on each function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

if you want an attribute value - if you want to use the value in some css rules then

```
$('#list ul li').attr('data-number', function(idx) {
    return idx + 1
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hm9bg/)

or use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), if you want to use the value only in some scripts later. This value can be later retrieved by using `$(el).data('number')`

```
$('#list ul li').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).data('number', idx + 1)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QCHVm/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
var dataList = function() {

var ul1 = $("#list").child("ul:first");
var ul2 = $("#list").child("ul:last");

ul1.each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('data-number',idx + 1);
});

ul2.each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('data-number',idx + 3);
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I think Chris and Arun solutions are more dynamic since I will have much more ul and li in my list